# Comparing int to a number

Tags: java, android

Ok i have a small problem i dont know what is wrong but i think it is something with the if statement and just to know joker4 i a global variable and it is set to 3 but when i try this function it doesnt go into the if statement in this code:

```
public void joker4(View view) {
    Button netocan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button netocan2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button netocan3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    if (joker4 != 0) {
        netocan.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        netocan2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        netocan3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        joker4 = joker4 - 1;
    } else {
        Toast joker1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Not enought JOKERS4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        joker1.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to just do a simple print out of joker4 right before the if statement to verify what it is at that point?

Comment: You are comparing the numbers in the right way, there a two possibilitys, joker4 is 0 or the if statement is executed but you dont realised it.

Comment: Your function Names also having the joker4 so you should change the Name that is the problem

Comment: @NaveenKumar: No, it's not. You can have a method and a field with the same name in Java.

Comment: @NaveenKumar it's not causing error, though it's confusing and a bad programming style.

Comment: @Dipika: That's not how Java works at all. There's no such thing as "the address of a function".

Comment: You just confirm your joker4 value at the step of IF condition but i tried this type of sample It works well for me I think Your Joker4 Value may have the problem

Comment: *"it is set to 3"* - How do you know that?

Comment: Because i have i textview in the xml and it shows the value of joker4

Comment: @user3402198 Are you sure it is showing the correct value? Are you sure the value has not changed by the time this method is called? Print out the value in your method, like mig and Naveen suggest.

Comment: Just for checking change the variable name of joker4 to something else

Comment: @AnasReza: Why? The fact that the method is also called `joker4` is a complete red herring here. It's irrelevant.

Comment: Can you tell the type of joker4?

Comment: It is an iteger value

Comment: @user3402198 can u show the full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the full code:**

```
package com.peky.smartornot;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class POV1 extends Activity {
    Sql ulaz= new Sql(this);
    int ispravka=0;
    int brojac = 0, brojac1 = 0, brojac2 = 0, joker1,joker2,joker3,joker4;
    TextView joke4text;
    TextView joke3text;
    TextView joke2text;
    TextView joke1text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pov1);
        sve();
    }
public void sve() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int joker1,joker2,joker3,joker4;
        ulaz.open();
        joker1=ulaz.procitaj();
        joker2=ulaz.procitaj2();
        joker3=ulaz.procitaj3();
        joker4=ulaz.procitaj4();
        ulaz.close();
        TabHost joker = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        joker.setup();
        TabSpec izgled = joker.newTabSpec("tag1");
        izgled.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        izgled.setIndicator("Joker 1");
        joker.addTab(izgled);
        izgled = joker.newTabSpec("tag2");
        izgled.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        izgled.setIndicator("Joker 2");
        joker.addTab(izgled);
        izgled = joker.newTabSpec("tag3");
        izgled.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        izgled.setIndicator("Joker 3");
        joker.addTab(izgled);
        izgled = joker.newTabSpec("tag4");
        izgled.setContent(R.id.tab4);
        izgled.setIndicator("Joker 4");
        joker.addTab(izgled);
        joke1text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.joker1text);
        joke1text.setText("You have "+ joker1 +" jokers !");
        joke2text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.joker2text);
        joke2text.setText("You have "+ joker2 +" jokers !");
        joke3text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.joker3text);
        joke3text.setText("You have "+ joker3 +" jokers !");
        joke4text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.joker4text);
        joke4text.setText("You have "+ joker4 +" jokers !");
    }
    public void joker4(View view) {
        Button netocan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button netocan2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button netocan3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        if(joker4!=0){
        netocan.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        netocan2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        netocan3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        joker4=joker4-1;
        }else{Toast joker1=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not enought JOKERS4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        joker1.show();

        }
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pov1, menu);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: In your method joker4 just log your value of variable joker4 just before the if statement

Comment: The variable you are using in joker4 method in if statement is the global variable and you haven't initialized that variable

Comment: Thazs true but in sve() it is set to the loaded value which is 3 but when the joker4 method is called it goes to -1 and it should be 2

Comment: In sve method you are using the joker4 method which is defined inside that method

Comment: Ok i initialized it and it works, can i set i outside this function so it loads faster

Answer (score -4):

I guess you need to resolve the ambiguity there.
The Variable-Joker4 and The function named Joker-4,
may be renaming the function might help your cause.

Comment: No, in Java it's perfectly legal to have a method with the same name as a variable.

Comment: What I am talking about is AMBIGUITY mate,
at this line of code:  if (joker4 != 0),
how about checking it once with a different function name?

Comment: There *is* no ambiguity here. There would be in other languages, but in Java there's no such ambiguity. In the condition `joker4 != 0`, `joker4` *unambiguously* refers to a variable, not a method.